# As a user signing up to reward a user for their answer found via Google; Is earning 15 rep necessary before being allowed to?

Tags: discussion, privileges, up-votes

I found a very elegant answer to a question and considered signing up to let the user know they helped me by giving an up vote. After considering my signup options I was about to skip signing up but I that I really wanted to let this user know they had really helped me out.

Upon attempting to give an up vote or even a comment I was blocked as messaged popped up letting me know I did not have enough reputation.

I understand rep is a large part of this website but when a user signs up to honestly reward someone (after considering not signing up) maybe the barrier for entry is a little high?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an anti-cheat measure. If a person could start voting for things immediately after signing up, imagine what a person who wanted to artificially inflate their reputation could do. I mean, if it's trivially easy to create a new account and vote for your stuff, why wouldn't you?

In lieu of voting, if you're not planning to stick around and participate, you could thank someone by spreading around (on social media, etc.) a link to the answer you found so helpful. More views will likely lead to more upvotes. It will, at the very least, boost their "people reached" score.